# jquery find id of div

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Hy,

I have this jquery code , what it does is saving in database (through ajax) the position of div in a database , 
but i don`t know how to get the id of div dragged , on the drop event

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('.dragDiv').Drags({
        handler: '.handler',
        onMove: function (e) {
            //$('.content').html('Div Position:(Left:' + e.pageX + ' ,Top:' + e.pageY + ')');
            //$('.content').html(done);
        },
        onDrop: function (e) {
            //$('.content').html('dropped!' + e.pageX);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'includes/scripts/data.php',
                data: "top=" + e.pageX + "&left=" + e.pageY + ""
            });
        }
    });
    $('.dragDiv2').Drags({
        handler: '.handler2',
        zIndex: 200,
        opacity: .9
    });
});
```

Comment: What's `Drags`? Why don't you use jQuery UI?

Comment: can you post a link to the `Drags` plugin ? but as @SLaks, says you should try the [jQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('.dragDiv').attr("id");
```

---

**EDIT**

If you would like to try this, you can try getting the id in the onDrag function using:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Verify that this is the correct id for the div, and if it is, this would be the recommended methodology.

---

**EDIT**
Good point 'Shadow Wizard'

```
var id = this.id;
```

---

**EDIT**

If all the previous methods have failed, use the jQuery event target:

```
var $target = $(e.target);
var id = null;
if($target.hasClass('dragDiv')) {
    id = $target[0].id;
} else {
    id = $target.parents('.dragDiv').first()[0].id;
}
```

This should go into your `onDrag` method.

Comment: I would normally recommend `$(this).attr('id')` in the onDrag, but I'm not familiar with Drag framework used here...there's no way to know if the `this` pointer in the onDrag is being set properly.

Comment: my point is that this code (*and in general selecting by `class` to find an `id`*) only works for unique elements in the DOM with that class..

Comment: if i use any of this it tells me undefined

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli - I completely agree with you; just for clarification, I fell back to the class method (even though it requires the assumption of a unique element) only b/c there is no way to know how the `this` in `onDrag` works.  In the future, I will ask for clarification from the author.

Comment: @user1069937 - what do you mean by all of this?  Do you mean all the methods listed failed to work; or do you mean that using the `this.id` gave undefined?

Comment: all the `onDrag` should be `onDrop`

Comment: this.id , var id = $(this).attr('id'); gave undefined

Comment: @user1069937 - I've given a new solution utilizing the jQuery event.  Please let us know if that works.  Good luck!

Comment: it does not work . now when i release the click button the script jams and i can`t release the div . where ever i go with the mouse the div does not get dropped

Comment: hmm...can you try replacing the code with `alert(e.target)`.  It should give you an object.  If that works then `alert($(e.target).length)` should give you 1.  Please verify.

Comment: i have deleted your code and used alert($(e.target).length) and gave me 1 . what should i do next ?

Comment: `alert($(e.target).attr("class"));` also do `alert($(e.target).parents('.dragDiv').length);`  Please let me know the results.

Comment: the first gives me handler and the second gives me 1 , it must give me the id 0 , because this is the id of the div "dragDiv"

Comment: i have managed it , thank you very much . alert($(e.target).parents('.dragDiv').attr("id"));

Comment: try `alert($(e.target).parents('.dragDiv').first().attr('id'));`

Comment: @user1069937 - great && good job :)... just include .first(). as in my last comment!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use the "this" keyword to get the object that is being dragged.

So that would mean you could write `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: `this.id` is enough - no need to wrap it as jQuery object.

Comment: if i use any of this it tells me undefined

Comment: I don't know the drags jquery but maybe you can get the id out of the e variable that is passed to your function? You should inspect this element in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this `.Drags()` plugin but logically  using `this.id` inside its event handlers should be enough..

Comment: if i use any of this it tells me undefined